# How to use the definition of limit and that inequality to deduce that $|f(x, t)|\ge \mu |t|^p - c_{\mu}$, $\mu, c_{\mu}>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, inequality

Let $p>1$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open bounded subset and $f:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that:
$$1)\qquad \lim_{|t|\to +\infty}\frac{f(x, t)}{|t|^p} =+\infty \quad\text{ uniformly for a.e. $x\in\Omega$}$$
and
$$2)\qquad c_1, c_2>0 \text{ and $q\ge 1$ exist such that } |f(x, t)|\le c_1+c_2|t|^q \text{ a.e. in $\Omega$, for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.}$$

From conditions $1)$ and $2)$ it should be possible to deduce (it is part of a proof I'm studying) that for all $\mu>0$ a constant $c_{\mu}>0$ exists so that
$$|f(x, t)|\ge \mu |t|^p - c_{\mu}.$$

My question is: why is that true?

The only thing I am able to deduce from condition $1)$ is:
$$\text{for all $R>0$ exists $M=M(R)>0$ such that }|f(x, t)|\ge M |t|^p \text{ for } |t|\ge R.$$

How to deduce from that the desired result?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @CalvinKhor yes, I made a typing error. Thank you for your useful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everything is uniform in $x$, we will drop $x$ in the notation completely. Fix $\mu>0$. Then by condition 1 there exists $R_\mu$ such that  $|f(t)| \ge \mu |t|^p$ for all $|t|\ge R_\mu$. In particular, for any $c\ge 0$, $|f(t)|\ge \mu|t|^p-c$.

On the set $|t|\le R_\mu$, just define $$c_\mu:=\max\Big(0,\sup_{|s|\le R_{\mu}}(\mu|s|^p -|f(s)|)\Big).$$
Note that $-|f(s)|\le 0$ so  $c_\mu\in [0,\mu |R_\mu|^p)$.  A little rearranging gives $|f(t)| \ge \mu|t|^p - c_\mu$, which also holds for $|t|\ge R_\mu$, which was what we wanted.